# Changing of HTML form element in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

i want to replace the html form action with another text using python not django

i tried this

```
import requests
import re
main_input = input()
get_input = requests.get(main_input).read()
get_inputtxt = get_input.text
re_pattern = re.search('^action.*"$', get_inputtxt)
open_file = open('hello.htm', 'w')
print(get_inputtxt, file=open_file)
if (re_pattern):
  re_pattern = re_pattern.replace(re_pattern, "action='hello.php'")
  open_file.close()


normal action = "www.me.html"
expected action = "hello.php"
```

Comment: You might want to look into BeautifulSoup - [https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/] instead of using `re`


  [1]:

Comment: i tried that also and when anytime i search form[0] it returns the actual opening form including it's attribute but return false if i tried searching for the action word in it though it's present

Comment: form may not have `action`. If there is no `action` then it sends to url from which it was loaded. First check manually if there is `action` in file.

Comment: I see two problems. First `^` - it search word `action` at the beginning of line - because you use `^` - but word `action` normally is inside `<form action...>`. Second `re_pattern` - you use it in two places in `re_pattern.replace(re_pattern, ...)` and I think it is incorrect.

Comment: yeah so how do i extract the whole action element from the <form action...... > tag and you're right.. i shoudn't have added the ^ but im still new to regular expression.. i've been usng ' if ' and for-loop earlier but that won't work here

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you would do it using [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/]):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
HTML = """
<form id="some_id" action="www.me.html" method="post">
   <input name="nothing" value="">
</form>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(HTML, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

```
<form action="www.me.html" id="some_id" method="post"> 
<input name="nothing" value=""/> </form>
```

```py
for form in soup('form'):
    print(form)
    form['action'] = "hello.php"

print(soup)
```

```
<form action="hello.php" id="some_id" method="post"> 
<input name="nothing" value=""/> </form>
```

You would just need to add the url request:

```
import requests
main_input = input()
HTML = requests.get(main_input).text
```

Comment: Thanks man, that really work but when writing the newly generated source code to a text file, it's throwing out an unicodeEncodeError

Comment: You might need to play around with `BeautifulSoup(page, fromEncoding=)` and `r.encoding` (https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content)